# Column format in excel, yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss

Tags: excel, csv, datetime

I need to set my column in Excel to yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss. When I open my csv file in VSCode, the format is correct, but when I open it in Excel, the written data in column is yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm. When i click the cell, the format displayed on formula bar was yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss. Does anyone know how to appear the data correctly in the cell? Thank you :/

[image]

Comment: What kind of data do you have in your Excel file? Select a cell with the Date/Time in it and change the format to `General`. Advise whether the displayed value changes to a number or remains as *yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm* date.

Comment: When i change  the format into general, the displayed value changes to a number with decimal.

Comment: csv files, when opened in Excel remove any formatting that has been applied, you would need to save it as a non-csv file in order to keep the formatting.

Comment: The problem appears to be perhaps not in the file format but between the file formats. You appear to be juggling VSCode, CSV and Excel. We might guess at what's happening if you would disclose your workflow step by step, but to what avail? Can you reduce your question to a statement like, "my CSV file has date/time values with 7 digits and Excel refuses to display seconds"? Lots of people here would doubt that you know how to set a *Custom* cell format, already explained by @amitklein below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply enter `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss` to the custom option (the one at the buttom).

[image]

Comment: I've done this, but when I re-open the file. The cell is no longer shows the format, it shows yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm  instead. But when I click the cell, the formula bar shows yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss. Can look at the printscreen on the edited question.

Comment: CVS have some data loss then saving the file, to overcome this just save in Excel format (if you use it in a program it will still work because the data is there.